# What is the purpose of Feature in Azure DevOps Agile workflow?

Tags: azure-devops

So I´m looking at the [Agile Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/agile-process-workflow?view=vsts) in Azure DevOps and I´m wondering, what´s the purpose of the Feature work item?

I´ve used Jira a lot and we only used Epics->User Stories->Tasks.

I can´t fine any good explanation to why Microsoft has added this WIT to their default workflow.

Comment: Sorry, didn´t know where else to sak this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here, [Adding Features and Epics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/define-features-epics?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)

I think of it this way, you would define a feature flag around code for a feature because it's a single shippable unit of testable code, but you wouldn't do the same for an epic because it's a hodgepodge of stories related to a business initiative. Having the two WITs allows you to clearly delineate those two needs and to map the user stories accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need. But what they write is very different from what is being taught to people writing requirements in general.